# How do we know a particular command was executed by whom?

Tags: linux, command-history

I want to know which user has executed `rm` command in production server?

Comment: See the `.bash_history` files in the home directories of each user for e.g. `bash` shells but note that a user can delete/modify it itself.

Comment: @phk really all that can be done in hindsight. The best strategy is to prevent this sort of thing ahead of time with proper file permissions on important files and auditing them if need be. And of course, nothing beats a good backup strategy.

Comment: use token for your users.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this if the server was configured to *audit* the use of the `rm` command as well as auditing the runtime functions `unlink` and `remove`.  The information would appear in the audit-logfiles.

Usually this is not done because that level of detail would use a lot of diskspace and make the system run slowly.

Further reading:

- [auditctl - a utility to assist controlling the kernel's audit system](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl)
- [7.5. Defining Audit Rules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Defining_Audit_Rules_and_Controls.html) (Red Hat Enterprise Linux - Security Guide)